# Maximized window's size

Tags: c#

I have a function that stores the size of my window by:

```
size_W = this.Width;
size_H = this.Height;
```

This is OK when I resize my window. However when Maximized button was used, the window's size cannot be stored properly.. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5):

Are you after the size of the window *before* it was maximized? In WinForms, this is saved in the [RestoreBounds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.restorebounds.aspx) property.

Answer (score 2):

The standard approach is to store both the Size **and** a boolean for `MainForm.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized`